# Get total count of each distinct value

Tags: powerbi

If I for example have a column of countries that might repeat and the list follows like this: `Spain, Spain, Italy, Spain`

I want to get the result that I take the number that a country appears in the column and divide it by total number. I have tried:

```
CountRows = DIVIDE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Report (7)'[Country]); COUNT('Report (7)'[Country]) )
```

Any suggestions? do I need a new column for that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this type of calculation is to add one column with the number of occurrence of the selected words divided by the number of row in the table.
You need to use the function Earlier to get the context.

If you have one table named Table1 and your column Country

Something like :

Divide(COUNTROWS(FILTER(table1, Table1[Country] = EARLIER(Table1[Country]))),COUNTROWS(Table1))

Don't forget to put your new column in Percentage type or add some decimal to see the correct data.